# Why aren't extremely dilute acid solutions basic in nature?

Tags: acid-base, ph

Lets say we prepare a solution of $\ce{HCl}$ with a concentration of  $\mathrm{10^{-8}}$. Even on full dissociation (which it will, because it is a strong acid), the $\ce{H+}$ ion concentration due to $\ce{HCl}$ is $\mathrm{10^{-8}}$.

So shouldn't the pH be 8? Is there any factor I am missing? Does the properties of acids change at low concentrations? If so, then how?

Comment: @Mithoron I got my answer. How do you get if a question is duplicate? I search for questions and hardly get relevant answers!

Comment: Must be my superior searching skills ;) There are some tips (https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3071/searching-guidelines-for-newbie) but practice is needed to be good at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Water is a weak acid, too. At that concentration of your acid, the number of hydronium ions from water will be roughly $10^{-7}$ molar, making the solution roughly neutral.